# Attribute Error using NeuralCoref in Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, spacy

I'm trying to use the following spacy module in colab:

https://spacy.io/universe/project/neuralcoref

I install the following packages:

```
!pip install spacy
import spacy 
!pip show spacy

!git clone https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref.git
import neuralcoref
```

I get the following output after installing:

```
Name: spacy
Version: 2.2.4
Summary: Industrial-strength Natural Language Processing (NLP) in Python
Home-page: https://spacy.io
Author: Explosion
Author-email: contact@explosion.ai
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: thinc, murmurhash, preshed, blis, srsly, cymem, setuptools, plac, requests, tqdm, numpy, wasabi, catalogue
Required-by: fastai, en-core-web-sm
Cloning into 'neuralcoref'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 48, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (48/48), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (44/44), done.
remote: Total 739 (delta 14), reused 10 (delta 1), pack-reused 691
Receiving objects: 100% (739/739), 67.86 MiB | 30.25 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (368/368), done.
```

I then follow the instructions on the website:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-fe99e1a1a10f> in <module>()
      1 nlp = spacy.load('en')
----> 2 neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)
      3 #coref = neuralcoref.NeuralCoref(nlp.vocab)
      4 #nlp.add_pipe(coref, name='neuralcoref')

AttributeError: module 'neuralcoref' has no attribute 'add_to_pipe'
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

**EDIT**

After (successfully) using the suggestion below, colab crashed on me when I tried to run the example provided (see details below).

Here is the code used:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

!pip install neuralcoref

import spacy
import neuralcoref

nlp = spacy.load('en') # this is the line where it crashes
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)

doc1 = nlp('My sister has a dog. She loves him.')
print(doc1._.coref_clusters)
```

I've attached a screenshot with the original error message at the bottom left.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I got the code to work on colab when changing the order of installing the modules (not sure why).

The following has worked for me now:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

!git clone https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref.git
!pip install -U spacy
!python -m spacy download en

import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

%cd neuralcoref

!pip install -r requirements.txt
!pip install -e .

import neuralcoref
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)

doc1 = nlp('My sister has a dog. She loves him.')
print(doc1._.coref_clusters)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update:

Since the previous helped solving the first problem but created another problem, I have updated the answer.

According to `neuralcoref` page, for our version of Spacy, we need to manually install it from the source.

Also, try each of the following blocks in new cell in Colab, and `Restart Runtime` after installation.

```
mkdir temp

cd temp

!git clone https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref.git
!pip install -U spacy
!python -m spacy download en

cd neuralcoref

!pip install -r requirements.txt
!pip install -e .


import neuralcoref
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)

doc1 = nlp('My sister has a dog. She loves him.')
print(doc1._.coref_clusters)
```

[image: Solved]

Comment: quick follow up question - are you able to run the example on the website? I just tried and it crashes my session with an unknown error?

Comment: Yes, I took that screenshot from Colab. Wait I'll try

Comment: okay so for me it crashs as soon as I add the following lines: doc1 = nlp('My sister has a dog. She loves him.')
print(doc1._.coref_clusters) is that the same for you?

Comment: ahh okay thanks - I just posted a new question, but will change it around now, thank you :-)

Comment: I had to add a % in front of the cd command in my colab for the installation to work, but then got a new error message where it can't find a model 'en'... I think I will have to make a new question for this! Thank you though!

Comment: That update solved that issue. Try that line: `!pip install -U spacy` 
`!python -m spacy download en`

Comment: yeah I tried the exact code, but that gives me an index error on the cd command? adding the % lets the code run but I get the error message on not being able to load 'en'...

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem. After a lot of debugging here is what I did to get it to work on google colab:

1. Install the right version of Spacy. My google colab had 2.2.4, but i reinstalled it like this:

```
pip install -U spacy==2.1.0 

python -m spacy download en
```

2. Google colab has the right version of Cython, but double check by running: !pip show cython. If not, install it with:

```
pip install Cython --install-option="--no-cython-compile"
```

The version needs to be >=0.25

3. Install neuralcoref like this. Make sure you are using GPU in google colab:

```
pip uninstall -y neuralcoref 

pip install neuralcoref --no-binary neuralcoref
```

That should fix it. Most likely the Spacy installation would do it for you, if not, follow all the steps.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Tested on 20 March 2022. Also, make sure that you factory reset the runtime so that it removes all previous installations of spacy and other dependencies.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

!git clone https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref.git

%cd neuralcoref

!pip install -r requirements.txt
!pip install -e .

import spacy
import neuralcoref

nlp = spacy.load('en')
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)
doc1 = nlp('My sister has a dog. She loves him.')
print(doc1._.coref_clusters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Neuralcoref just works with spacy Version

spacy>=2.1.0,<2.2.0
cython>=0.25
pytest

see [requirements.txt](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref/blob/master/requirements.txt)