# Another error to import spaCy neuralcoref module even following the sample code

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, jupyter-notebook, spacy

## What I would like to do

I would like to run the sample code for spaCy neuralcoref on jupyter notebook.

## Problem

After I asked my former questeion, [Error to import spaCy neuralcoref module even follwoing the sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62846108/error-to-import-spacy-neuralcoref-module-even-follwoing-the-sample-code), I have tried to install libraries following another answer to this issue on stackoverflow.

What should I do to run the sample code of spaCy neuralcoref?

### Problem 1

This part is executable, but notice and output are shown.

```
# Add neural coref to SpaCy's pipe
import neuralcoref
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)
```

notice

```
/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: spacy.morphology.Morphology size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 104 from C header, got 112 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: spacy.vocab.Vocab size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 112 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: spacy.tokens.span.Span size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
```

output

```
<spacy.lang.en.English at 0x114304c10>
```

### Problem 2

When I execute the below part, the popup error message is shown.

```py
doc1 = nlp('My sister has a dog. She loves him.')
print(doc1._.coref_clusters)
```

**popup error message on jupyter notebook**

```
Kernel Restarting
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

## Code

```py
# Load your usual SpaCy model (one of SpaCy English models)
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

# Add neural coref to SpaCy's pipe
import neuralcoref
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)

doc1 = nlp('My sister has a dog. She loves him.')
print(doc1._.coref_clusters)
```

## What I tried to do

I have tried to install libraries following [another answer to this issue on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61269954/attribute-error-using-neuralcoref-in-colab).

```
!git clone https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref.git
!pip install -U spacy
!python -m spacy download en

cd neuralcoref

!pip install -r requirements.txt
!pip install -e .
```

## Environment

Mac OS Catalina version 10.15.5

Python 3.7.4

spaCy 2.1.0

neuralcoref 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade to python `3.7`. neuralcoref works only for python `3.7` and spaCy 2.1.0.

The best way to fix this in opinion would be alter the requirements.txt of neuralcoref and change `spacy>=2.1.0,<2.2.0` to `spacy==2.1.0`

Hope that helps.